# Does using "chmod 666" on specific directories creates any vulnerability? (installing Kohana)

Tags: apache, permissions, kohana, chmod

Obviously I am very new, so please bear with me.

I installed Kohana Framework in my localhost. To do is so we have to set two specific folders with write permissions to all. "*chmod 666*" is suggested. ([here](http://code.google.com/p/maggie/wiki/KohanaDetails))

The remaining directories are set to 755.

My question is more directed to Apache.

- **Will the use of "*chmod 666*" create a vulnerability in a webserver?**
- **What exacly means "write access for everyone"?**

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

666 is almost always a really bad idea.  The web site where you read that needs a good flogging.

"Write access for everyone" means that anyone with a user account on your system can write to that directory.

Comment: What would you suggest? The framework specifically requires writing access to two directories.

Comment: Give read/write access only to the user that is running that software--and ideally that user should not be root!

Comment: An alternative might be to make apache create the folders, so then they can be set as writable owner only. Unfortunately you won't be able to delete the files, and other users might be able to use apache to get the files via some code on their site. The best option is to talk to your webhost about getting apache to either run as your user when serving your site. Or perhaps another user who's in a shared unix group with you, then use group-writable.

Answer (score 1):

These rights are only for your current server, so if you are the only one with access to a user account on your machine you should be pretty safe. Write access for everyone means everyone with a user account on your machine has the right to write. Please note that 3rd party software (like apache) can have it's own user as well and this could be compromised if there's a exploit in that software. This way someone from the outside could gain access to that folder. It's a common practice to only give rights to users that really need access.

Note: On a normal Windows machine (don't know if this is still true with Windows 7 though) everyone has access to everyone's files. So this is just another security measure.

Comment: Thank you for your good reply. What if your in a webhost online. Other users of the same webhost could hypothetically gain access to the 666-folders?

Comment: That depends on the configuration of the webhost, if it uses chroots for users they should not be able to access your files, if not it could be very well posible yes. Just to be safe make sure only your user got access.

Comment: Using Windows file permissions as the standard for security is a REALLY BAD IDEA!!!